# epoll/select for mutexes/semaphores

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous

When you have a set of pipes/sockets waiting for read/write, epoll() or select() can be used to wait on all of them until at least one of them are ready for read/write.

Is there anything similar for threads/pthreads? The closest I've got on doing this is making a sleeping thread by blocking on lock() for mutexes. However, this costs a thread for each lock.

I also thought about using pipes instead of these locks, but it also seems inefficient, and the pipe count seems to be limited to around 500 pipes (at least it's a little higher than threads).

So yeah, are there better solutions than using threads on waiting for mutexes to unlock?

Comment: I am not sure of your requirment here - wait for the threads to do.. what?  If you just want to wait until some thread reaches some point in its execution, yuo could just signal a common, single event or semaphore, as you hint at in your title. An event would tell you that at least one thread has reached your trigger point, a semaphore would allow you to tell how many had get there.  In either case, your could iterate the threads, (a 'ready' boolean in the threads), to find out which ones were at the trigger point.  Can you be a bit clearer re. your requirements?

Answer (score 7):

`eventfd` might be of use for you. They should work the same way as your pipes but the overhead is much much smaller.

If you're hitting the 1024 open files limit, you can increase it to as much as you want using ulimit. But, if you have many locks, there should some more intelligent use of the eventfd's.

Here's some more info: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such methods, but you might want to rethink the design leading to such a problem. If you are trying to wait for the availability of a number of mutexes in unspecified order (probably locking some of them in the process), the Dining Philosophers problem seems very likely to lurk just around the corner.

If that's not the problem, a condition variable is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for conditional variables. See man pages for pthread_cond_init, pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal.

If one thread call pthread_cond_wait(cond) it waits until the second thread calls pthread_cond_signal(cond)